# Java libgdx android - My own asset file is not loading

Tags: java, android, file, libgdx, assets

I'm new in libgdx and I'm trying to do some tutorials. I have problem with loading my own `.png` file.

Standard project contains `libgdx.png` file and it works. When I run it on desktop or android it works fine. Images display well.

The same code, just another file (also `png`).
Works fine on desktop version, but it cannot run on android.

I really dont understand what happens, because files (libgdx.png and my.png) are in the same folder and first one works on android but the second one doesnt...

```
public class AwesomeGame implements ApplicationListener {
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture man;
Texture abc;
Vector2 position;

@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    man = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("my.png"));
    position = new Vector2(50,50);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)){
        position.y+=1f;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)){
        position.y-=1f;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)){
        position.x+=1f;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)){
        position.x-=1f;
    }

    if(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX()!=0){
        position.x-=Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
    }
    if(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY()!=0){
        position.y+=Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
    }

    batch.setColor(position.x,position.y,10,10);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(man, position.y, position.x);
    batch.end();
}
```

Can someone explain me that ? ;(

Comment: Save your png image with other software, I had similar problem and I solved with saving png with for example blender or gimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

omg, I got it.

Texture width and height must be a power of 2.

but if I set

```
cfg.useGL20 = true;
```

everything works without power of 2.

Comment: opengl 2.0 im pretty sure does not require textures to be in the power of two, hence the reason that is working. also opengl 1.0 is going to be phased out of libgdx pretty soon